# Getting the response from axios passed on Session storage (user authtoke) with React works fine only once and never again

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

I am learning how to create react Apps and got myself in very deep hole that I cannot leave by myself, so I've decided to reach out for help of the most spectacular people out there that are you! :)

When I run my App for the first time everything goes well until I logout and I try to log back in again and my session storage is not updated with the function.

It happens that after I run yarn add axios it works just fine and if I logout I have to run the command 'yarn add axios' and restart my server to get my login working for once more.
It is a pain in the neck.

I hope someone out there with fresh eyes can help me out on this.
**Thank you so much!**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";

import NavBar from "./components/navbar/NavBar";
import { SERVER_URL } from "./config.js";
import axios from "axios";

import "./index.css"

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let auth = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("auth"));
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: !!auth ? true : false,
      currentUser: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
    let auth = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("auth"));
    if (!auth) return;

    axios
      .get(`${SERVER_URL}/api/users/${auth.userId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}` }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: response.data,
          isLoggedIn: true
        });
      });
  }

  handleLogin(email, password) {
    axios
      .post(`${SERVER_URL}/api/auth/get_token`, {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        this.getUser();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err)
      });
  }

  handleLogout() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("auth", null);
    this.setState({ currentUser: null, isLoggedIn: false });
  }

  render() {
    const userProps = {
      isLoggedIn: this.state.isLoggedIn,
      currentUser: this.state.currentUser,
      logout: () => this.handleLogout(),
      login: (email, pass) => this.handleLogin(email, pass)
    };

    return (
      <>
        <NavBar user={userProps}></NavBar>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Rails backend that seems to be working well:

```
def get_by_id

      user = User.find(params[:user_id])

        if user
            render json: { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email},
                   status: :ok
        else
            render json: { errors: 'User not found' }, status: :not_found
        end
  end

  def get_token

        user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

        if !user
            render json: { error: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
            return
        end

        if !user.authenticate( params[:password] )
            render json: { error: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
            return
        end

        token = jwt_encode({user_id: user.id}, 24.hours.from_now)
        render json: {token: token, exp: 24, username: user.email, userId: user.id},
               status: :ok
        return

  end
```

The Json file that is returned by the backend looks good to me:

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE1NzY3MzcxOTZ9.aK7oLuHZ1r-aI8t-QVT0kV-i5mTYb3B9NiacWJJD9aU",
    "exp": 24,
    "username": "a@a.com",
    "userId": 1
}

But even after getting an apparently good response from the backend I still cannot update my sessionStorage more than once =/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error? Or are you getting the response from get_token api when you retried login?

You don't need to **yarn add axios** everytime. If you think axios is the problem then you can use fetch api for http requests.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I have gone with fetch as you suggested, then. All good so far.